# Python; for loop; iterating over an existing variable set

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, iteration, pythonanywhere

Suppose I have a set of variables which are already created. They use a similar (i.e. predictable naming convention). Example:

```
job0 = "X"
job1 = " "
job2 = " "
job3 = "X"
job4 = "X"
```

My aim is to be able to iterate over these variables and check whether or not they contain a "X". These variables are 'auto-generated' by another `for` loop.

Here is a longer example of the code I am experimenting with:

```
job_count_array = []
global job_count
for i in range(2, job_count+1):
    job_count_array.append("sel.get_text(//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small)" % i)
print job_count_array #output for debug purposes
for l, value in enumerate(job_count_array):
    exec "job%d = value" % l #auto-generates variables with the above list indices
```

So, as you can see I get the variables generated through `$`enumerate`$` iteration. I can't seem to find a way to check whether or not these auto-generated variables (i.e. job0, job1, job2, job3, etc) contain either an "X" or a blank space " ". Here is my attempt:

```
for i in range(0, job_count-1):
    print "job%d" % i
    if "job%d" % i == "X":
        print "Excluding Job%d: Found Locked Status" % i
        #I plan to add code to this line that will allow me to exclude the job this variable refers to for further testing/evaluation
    if job%d % i == " ":
        print "Including Job%d: Found Unlocked Status" % i
        #I plan to add code to this line that will allow me to include the job this variable refers to for further testing/evaluation
```

Comment: Don't use numbered variables. Use a *list* instead, or at best a dictionary. You *already **have** a list* even, `job_count_array`.

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: So, a method call in a list indice will function the same as if I assigned it to a variable?

Comment: You can pass `job_count_array[0]` to a method call, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Can you store a method call within a list indice? e.g. `code`job_count_array = ['sel.get_text(//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/small)']

Comment: You can store *anything* you can store in a variable, in a list index as well. A method call returns a value, you can store that return value in a list. You can even store a reference to the method itself in a list index.

Comment: Okay, so I have to store the return value in the list? Because as of now I am storing the method call.

Comment: Then remove the quotes; `self.get_text()` is the method call, it returns a value, just store that in the list: `job_count_array.append(sel.get_text("//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/small)" % i))`

Comment: By Jove I think you've got it! Thanks, Martijn :)

Comment: I already tried initially, but I get a raised exception (i.e. not enough reputation points yet).

Comment: Martijn, is there a way to do the immediate above (i.e. your comment, "Then remove the quotes;"), but instead of using append to apply it to a list return the method call to a dictionary value?

Comment: Sure; `dictionary[somekey] = ...` assigns to a dictionary value.

Comment: I am waiting for an html table to populate on a webserver. When this table populates it will have at least two rows. The first row is to be ignored because it is the row of labels for each column. The second row is where the data begins. The amount of rows which have data will be dynamic/variable/unknown. I can get the count of all rows of the table and I know when I subtract one from that count I get the rows of data. Each 'data row' has a cell which I am testing if it has a value of 'X' or a ' ' (space). If the cell has a space I need to somehow keep track of that row/those rows xpath addy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list: `job_count_array`. All you have to do now is loop over that list:

```
for job in job_count_array:
    if job == "X":
        # etc.
```

This lets you drop the loop with `exec` calls too. See how much easier that is? Just [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Whenever you find you want to generate dynamic variables, generate a list or dictionary instead, they are *far easier* to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Martijn Pieters advice.

That said, I will answer your original question.

The variables are stored in a dictionary called *globals*.  You can loop over those and print matches:

```
 for varname, value in globals().values():
     if varname.startswith('job') and value == 'X':
         ...
```

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to Upvote you, sorry. I tried to select both answers as correct seeing that you both contributed in important ways. I don't know how to reward you, sorry!

Comment: No worries.  Glad you got your answer.